# How to undelete records from Recycle Bin for Notes and Attachments

Tags: apex, class

I am trying to build one custom visualforce page from where I can Undelete Note and Attachments Both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the something like this in my dev Org and it working fine :

please find the below code :

Apex Class : -

```
public class UndeleteRecsController
{

    Public List<Note> noteList{get;set;}//List of Notes
    Public List<Attachment> attachList{get;set;}//List of Attachment
    Public List<wrapNote> wrapperlist {get;set;} // wrapper list for note to show this in the page
    Public List<wrapAttach> wrapperlistattach {get;set;}// wrapper list for Attachments to show this in the page
    public string pId;// Store the parent Id
    public String selected_option{get;set;} // store what is selected from page
    public Boolean enableNote{get;set;}//To enable section for Note
    public Boolean enableAttach{get;set;}//To enable section for Attachment

    //Controller to initialize all the List 
    public UndeleteRecsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        pId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Pid');
        noteList = New List<Note>();
        attachList = New List<Attachment>();
        wrapperlist  = new List<wrapNote>();   
        wrapperlistattach = new List<wrapAttach>();  

    }   

    Public UndeleteRecsController()    {

    }

    //to Show options in the Page
    public  List<SelectOption> getSearchOption()
    {        
        List<SelectOption> filter_search= new List<SelectOption>(); 
        filter_search.add(new SelectOption('Notes','Notes'));
        filter_search.add(new SelectOption('Attachments','Attachments'));        
        return filter_search; 
    } 

    //Populate the section based on the selection
    public void populate()
    {
        if(selected_option =='Notes')
        {
           System.debug('----name--------');
           enableNote = true ; 
           enableAttach = false; 
           populaterecord();           
        }    
        else if(selected_option =='Attachments')
        {
           enableNote = false; 
           enableAttach = true;  
           populaterecord();        
        }       
    }

    //populate list for both note and attachments
    Public void populaterecord()
    {
        if(selected_option =='Notes')
        {
            wrapperlist  = new List<wrapNote>();
            //Query records for Notes based on the parent Id
            noteList = [select id,Title,Body from Note where isdeleted =: true and ParentId =:pId ALL rows];
            if(noteList.size()>0)
            {
                for(Note no : noteList)
                {
                    wrapperlist.add(new wrapNote(no,false));
                }
            }
        }
        if(selected_option =='Attachments')
        {
            wrapperlistattach = new List<wrapAttach>();  
            //Query records for Attachment based on the parent Id
            attachList = [select Id,ParentId,Name,ContentType  from Attachment where isdeleted =: true and ParentId =:pId ALL rows];
            if(attachList.size()>0)
            {
                for(Attachment no : attachList)
                {
                    wrapperlistattach.add(new wrapAttach(no,false));
                }
            }            
        }

    }

    //after Selecting records un-delete functionality 
    ublic void UndeleteRecs()
    {
        if(selected_option =='Notes')
        {
            List<Note> lstselectedNote = new List<Note>();          
            for(wrapNote wrapno : wrapperlist)
             {
                 if(wrapno.selectedrecord== true)
                 {
                    //Adding Selected note which needs to be undelete
                     lstselectedNote.add(wrapno.nt);
                 }
             }
             if(lstselectedNote.size()>0)
             {
                 //Un_delete selected Attachment
                 undelete lstselectedNote ;      
                 populaterecord();        
             }
        }
        if(selected_option =='Attachments')
        {
             List<Attachment> lstselectedAttach = new List<Attachment>();  
             for(wrapAttach wrapno : wrapperlistattach)
             {
                 if(wrapno.selectedrecord== true)
                 {
                     //Adding Selected Attachment which needs to be undelete
                     lstselectedAttach.add(wrapno.att);
                 }
             }
             if(lstselectedAttach.size()>0)
             {
                 //Un_delete selected Attachment
                 undelete lstselectedAttach;      
                 populaterecord();        
             }

        }
    }

    ////preparing wrapper class for Notes
    public class wrapNote
    {
        public Note nt{get; set;}
        public Boolean selectedrecord{get; set;}      

        public wrapNote(Note n,Boolean isselecteduser)
        {               
            nt = n;
            selectedrecord = isselecteduser;
        }    
    }

    //preparing wrapper class for attachment
    public class wrapAttach
    {
        public Attachment att{get; set;}
        public Boolean selectedrecord{get; set;}      

        public wrapAttach(Attachment t,Boolean isselecteduser)
        {               
            att = t;
            selectedrecord = isselecteduser;
        }    
    }

}
```

Visulforce Page : -

```
<apex:page controller="UndeleteRecsController">

<c:Overlay style="processing"/>
<apex:form id="frm">
<script>
    function reloadPage()
    {
      var idd = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
      window.top.location='/'+idd;
    }
</script>

    <div id="overlay"></div> 

    <apex:pageBlock id="pgdblk"> 
      <apex:actionStatus id="searchStatus"  onstart="showOverlay();" onstop="hideOverlay();"/>
      <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="true" columns="1" title="Search Criteria" id="pgsecserch"> 
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="id_sec2">
                <apex:selectRadio value="{!selected_option}" >
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!SearchOption}"></apex:selectOptions> 
                     <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!populate}" reRender="pgdblk,avai_per,avai_att" status="searchStatus"/>
                </apex:selectRadio>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>            
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="Available Note" id="avai_per" columns="1"  rendered="{!enableNote}">
            <apex:outputPanel id="id_available">
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="asslpgd" value="{!wrapperlist}" var="cus">
                  <apex:column headerValue="Select" style="width:40px">                                                  
                       <apex:inputCheckbox id="selectcheckbox" value="{!cus.selectedrecord}"/>                    
                  </apex:column>                       
                  <apex:column headerValue="Title">                       
                       <apex:outputText value="{!cus.nt.Title}"/>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Body">                       
                       <apex:outputText value="{!cus.nt.Body}"/>
                  </apex:column>                      
               </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>           
            <center><apex:commandButton value="Undelete" action="{!UndeleteRecs}" reRender="pgdblk,avai_per,asslpgd" status="searchStatus" onclick="reloadPage()"/></center>                                               
        </apex:pageBlockSection> 

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Available Attachment" id="avai_att" columns="1" rendered="{!enableAttach}">
            <apex:outputPanel id="id_att">
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="assatt" value="{!wrapperlistattach}" var="cus">
                  <apex:column headerValue="Select" style="width:40px">                                                  
                       <apex:inputCheckbox id="selectcheckbox" value="{!cus.selectedrecord}"/>                    
                  </apex:column>                       
                  <apex:column headerValue="Title">                       
                       <apex:outputText value="{!cus.att.Name}"/>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Content Type">                       
                       <apex:outputText value="{!cus.att.ContentType}"/>
                  </apex:column>                      
               </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>            
            <center><apex:commandButton value="Undelete" action="{!UndeleteRecs}" reRender="pgdblk,avai_att,assatt" status="searchStatus" onclick="reloadPage()"/></center>                                               
        </apex:pageBlockSection>           
    </apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

It should work,but next time onward please post your requirement elaborately.Also post what you have tried so far.